# Need help on python 3x on creating an input string that gives a true or false output

Tags: python-3.x

Each single digit from 0-9 is valid.

two or more digits are valid as long as it doesn't start with 0.

x+y 
x-y 
x/y
x*y
are valid expressions

Nothing else is a valid expression

Comment: I would first check for any characters not whitelisted via regular expressions. Then use an expression parsing technique. Maybe you could make use of `sympy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you need based on those rules : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwgaO.png

```
import re

userInput = input("Enter expression : ")
if re.match(r'^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)([\+\-\*/]([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+))*$', userInput):
  print("Valid expression")
else:
  print("Invalid expression")
```

## Here's some explanation of the regex used :

"`^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)([\+\-\*/]([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+))*$`"

#### First part : `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)`

You either match a single digit within range 0-9 or 2+ digits with the first digit within range 1-9 (excluding 0)

#### Second part : `([\+\-\*/]&first_part)*`

First of all you search for any of these operators : + - * /, you need to escape +, - and * characters because they are used in the Python regex syntax. No need to escape the / character though.

The * at the end means you expect the second part to be repeated 0 or more times.

## What if I don't want to use regexes ?

```
userInput = input("Expression : ")
allowedDigits, allowedOPs = [str(a) for a in range(10)], ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
pile = ""
valid = True

for c in userInput:
  if c in allowedDigits and pile != "" and pile[0] == "0": valid = False
  elif c in allowedDigits: pile += c
  elif c in allowedOPs and pile == "": valid = False
  elif c in allowedOPs: pile = ""
  else: valid = False
if pile == "": valid = False

if valid:
  print("Valid Expression !")
else:
  print("Invalid Expression !")
```

This code is pretty simple and straightforward, we just detect the 4 possible fail cases :

> The number contains more than one digit and begins with 0

```
if c in allowedDigits and pile != "" and pile[0] == "0"
```

> There's an operator and no number before

```
elif c in allowedOPs and pile == ""
```

> There's a non-allowed character

```
else
```

> Expression ends with an operator (doesn't end with a number)

```
if pile == ""
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how it works, I will try recreate this in my own version. Its a much simpler version from what I was trying to accomplish and easier to understand.

Comment: Is there another method without using regex?

Comment: Added a method that doesn't require any regexes